# Add QWidget to QListWidget

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside

I am trying to make a QListWidget in which each item is a simple widget that contains text and a pushbutton. I use the following:

```
itemN = QtGui.QListWidgetItem() 
#Create widget
widget = QtGui.QWidget()
widgetText =  QtGui.QLabel("I love PyQt!")
widgetButton =  QtGui.QPushButton("Push Me")
widgetLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
widgetLayout.addWidget(widgetText)
widgetLayout.addWidget(widgetButton)
widgetLayout.addStretch()
widget.setLayout(widgetLayout)
#Add widget to QListWidget funList
funList.addItem(itemN)
funList.setItemWidget(itemN, widget)
```

The problem is, nothing shows up. I get a blank line that I can navigate using my keyboard, but it is blank. When the widget contains *just* a pushbutton, it works, so it isn't as if the pushbutton alone is messing things up. Are there limits on the complexity of widgets that `setItemWidget` can handle? Perhaps I need to go beyond the convenience classes, as suggested in some of the related posts below?

**Related posts**

[pyqt adding a widget to a QListWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24417285/pyqt-adding-a-widget-to-a-qlistwidget)
Note the previous post has a similar title to mine, but seems to be a relatively poorly expressed question about a complex pastiche of code from QtDesigner (mixed with some custom stuff). It is not clear at all that this is actually the question the person should have been asking. While the title makes it seem like a duplicate, the question (I pray) is not.

I would say something similar about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23850696/populating-a-qlistwidget-with-custom-widgets) post.

[QListWidgetItem with Radio Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18904155/qlistwidgetitem-with-radio-button)

[QListView/QListWidget with custom items and custom item widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948444/qlistview-qlistwidget-with-custom-items)

[Adding Custom Widget to QListWidget in QT click issue in QT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063864/adding-custom-widget-to-qlistwidget-in-qt-click-issue-in-qt)

[pyqt adding a widget to a QListWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24417285/pyqt-adding-a-widget-to-a-qlistwidget)

http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/8660-Drawing-a-widget-in-QItemDelegate-s-paint-method

http://developer.nokia.com/community/discussion/showthread.php/211634-Adding-a-button-inside-QListWidgetItem

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try this:

```
itemN = QtGui.QListWidgetItem() 
#Create widget
widget = QtGui.QWidget()
widgetText =  QtGui.QLabel("I love PyQt!")
widgetButton =  QtGui.QPushButton("Push Me")
widgetLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
widgetLayout.addWidget(widgetText)
widgetLayout.addWidget(widgetButton)
widgetLayout.addStretch()

widgetLayout.setSizeConstraint(QtGui.QLayout.SetFixedSize)
widget.setLayout(widgetLayout)  
itemN.setSizeHint(widget.sizeHint())    

#Add widget to QListWidget funList
funList.addItem(itemN)
funList.setItemWidget(itemN, widget)
```

As you can see, you need `setSizeConstraint` to the layout and `setSizeHint` to item.

Comment: that works! It isn't super clear to me what's happening. 1) Once the size constraint is set, do I truly need to `setSizeHint` to the item too? It _seems_ leaving out `setSizeHint` doesn't change the appearance of my GUI.  2) Why did my size hint default to -1, -1 in the first place, and how does using 'SetFixedSize' fix this? Why doesn't it just fix it at the wrong value (-1, -1). Any good docs going over the ins-and-outs of these issues? (Docs include: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#SizeHint-enum and http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlayout.html#SizeConstraint-enum)

Comment: @neuronet `QLayout::SetFixedSize` The main widget's size is set to `sizeHint();` it cannot be resized at all. If you will not set size hint, your widget with label and button will be bigger then item, so it will be extremely ugly and uncorrect.

Comment: Accepting answer because it solved problem, but will definitely upvote anyone who explains the ins-and-outs of this, to bring next person beyond cargo cult programming :)

Answer (score 9):

If you use PyQt5, there is some changes, you must use `QtWidgets` for widget not `QtGui`. Use this code if using with PyQt5:

Don't forget to import PyQt5:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets`

itemN = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
# Create widget
widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
widgetText = QtWidgets.QLabel("I love PyQt!")
widgetButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Push Me")
widgetLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
widgetLayout.addWidget(widgetText)
widgetLayout.addWidget(widgetButton)
widgetLayout.addStretch()

widgetLayout.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetFixedSize)
widget.setLayout(widgetLayout)
itemN.setSizeHint(widget.sizeHint())

# Add widget to QListWidget funList
funList.addItem(itemN)
funList.setItemWidget(itemN, widget)
```

[image]

Comment: Cute, but it there a way to have these widget filled QListWidgetItems not turn out to be absolute chonkers? They're just too tall with wasted space.

Comment: @user1469620  try it: `widgetLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)`